# chrome.history.search startTime + endTime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

can I mix startTime and endTime in chrome.history.search query?
so that I can limit results for eg. yesterday?

this code gives me weird results (too many)

```
chrome.history.search({text:'', startTime: a, endTime:b, maxResults: 100000});
```

Comment: Both start and end time are used to specify the interval as can be seen in the source code ([1](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/history/history_api.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=322&rcl=1446884859), [2](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/history/core/browser/visit_database.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=355&rcl=1446884859)). Maybe you can investigate the issue and provide more details?

Comment: @wOxxOm a=1446768000000, b= 1446854400000. That is epoch time for yesterday.

Comment: @wOxxOm you can add **getTimezoneOffset()** to time in ms (multiplied with 60000). that's what I do now, and I'm getting the same results as browser.

Comment: Okay, so if you found the solution post it as an answer. And I'll delete my comments after the first one as those are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

the problem was in local time
before calling the history.search I added timezone offset to searched time in ms

```
//this is a global var and to be added to any timestamp in ms
var dateCurrent= new Date(), 
    correction = dateCurrent.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;


//now when calling history.search I'm calculating that correction in
//eg. for yestrday

var dN = Date.now(), 
d1 = dN%86400000,
b = correction + dN - d1,
a = b - 86400000;

chrome.history.search({text:'', startTime: a, endTime:b, maxResults: 100000}, function {
  //code
});
```

edit: fixed double correction